# Error in creating new tables in database

Tags: mysql

I want to add the following table to my database, but when I execute the script I get an error. I think I am missing something:

```
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login_users` (
      `hash` text,
      `photo` text,
      `bio` text,
      `facebook_id` text,
      `added_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `achievements` text,
      `last_seen` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `website_url` text,
      `facebook_url` text,
      `twitter_url` text,
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

The errors:

```
   debug : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULTCHARSET=utf8_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 12{"success":false,"error":"

     #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 12<\/div>"}
```

Comment: Extra comma after last column, remove it.

Comment: The error is self-explanatory.

Comment: Ha thank you friends, what anwser should i put for correct one?

Comment: Also check if your `DEFAULT` and `CHARSET` words got run together -- the error message seems to suggest they did.

Comment: @Romano The first one posted... You can sort by *oldest*

Comment: Now it says debug : #1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8_general_ci'{"success":false,"error":", i guess i need to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a redundant comma after the definition of `twitter_url`:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login_users` (
  `hash` text,
  `photo` text,
  `bio` text,
  `facebook_id` text,
  `added_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `achievements` text,
  `last_seen` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `website_url` text,
  `facebook_url` text,
  `twitter_url` text --Extra comma removed here
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an erroneous trailing comma.

```
`twitter_url` text, <--
)
```

Comment: you sholdnt answer `OFF TOPIC` questions.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last comma:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login_users` (
      `hash` text,
      `photo` text,
      `bio` text,
      `facebook_id` text,
      `added_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `achievements` text,
      `last_seen` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `website_url` text,
      `facebook_url` text,
      `twitter_url` text
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```